# would installing a brass ball valve against direction of water flow affect it's volume?

Tags: plumbing

I have very little water pressure coming through both my bathroom faucets. I just noticed the valve off the water heater is installed backwards And there are no other valves that I can see in between this and the bathroom.

Comment: "Both your bathroom faucets" - Hot AND Cold, or Hot only for Sink/Basin AND Tub/Shower? Has this just started, did it ever work right...?

Comment: How can you tell that it's backwards?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a 1/4 turn ball shutoff valve, they are not directional - there is no such thing as backwards for 99.95% of them (and for 0.05% it might make some difference in potential for a leak when closed, but none to water flow when open.)

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention only the bathroom faucets and nothing else (kitchen, shower, etc.), I would start at the faucets in question. Maybe they are newer and have a restricting aerator or valve components to meet local water saving requirements; maybe they are plugged up with debris; maybe the supply hoses are kinked; maybe the stop valves are not open all the way; maybe the stop valves are plugged; maybe the bathroom faucets were plumbed with under-size supply piping; maybe you could switch to high-quality full-port ball valves for your supply stops, etc...